# #if, #else, #endif in C# source code

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I've got a sample code from MSDN and I've found code syntax I've never seen before:

```
namespace Mvc3RemoteVal.Controllers 
{
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            IUserDB _repository;

#if  InMemDB
            public HomeController() : this(InMemoryDB.Instance) { }
#else
            public HomeController() : this(new EF_UserRepository()) { }
#endif


            public HomeController(IUserDB repository) 
            {
                _repository = repository;
            }

            [...]
        }
```

What are those `#if`, `#else`, `#endif`?

And what is `#if InMemDB`?

What is `InMemDB`? A variable?

Comment: As the other answers stated, those are not new in .Net 4.0, you may need to know they existed since C++ days.

Comment: He is saying preprocessor directives have existed since C / C++, not that C# is based off C++.

Comment: @Joey, What @yodaj007 is saying is right, I didn't mean heritage here.

Comment: Your question is answered in section 2.5 of the C# 4 specification; I encourage you to read it when you have questions about the language.

Comment: @Joey, you're moving the goal post.  No one here said they were the same.  Stop trying to start an argument.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are called [preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) and exist since .NET 1.0. They allow you to define different compilation directives such as `InMemDB` and the compiler will evaluate or not the block if this variable has been defined. The documentation of the [#if directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) provides a more in-depth overview.

In order to define a variable you could use the [/define](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) compiler option or use the *Conditional compilation symbols* in the *Build* tab of the properties of the project in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These are not new features for Framework 4

this are features you can use for development stage and testing:
you can declare:

```
#Define something
```

and then

```
#if something
```

all the code that is in that "if" will be executed.
all the code that isn't, won't.